# NSDate dateFromString returning null when pulling from RSS feed

Tags: ios, uitableview, rss

I am parsing a RSS feed in my app and putting each item into a table view cell. One of the pieces I am grabbing is the `pubDate`, which is a string that looks like this:

`Fri, 23 May 2014 10:00:00 GMT`

I am using the following code, but the `NSDate` continues to return null. However, if I manually enter the string (see commented out line) instead of trying to grab the `pubDate`, it works fine. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ReadingsCell *cell = (ReadingsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReadingsCell"];

    cell.readingLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    dateString = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"pubDate"];
    //dateString = @"Mon, 19 May 2014 10:00:00 GMT";
    NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
    //the above logs out perfectly

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

    NSDate *postDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    postDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

    NSLog(@"pubdate: %@", postDate);
    //this logs out as null

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    NSString *theMonth = [dateFormat stringFromDate:postDate];
    cell.monthLabel.text = theMonth;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"pubDate"] -> return String or Date? Should check it

Comment: @nmh, it returns a string. I am trying to take that string and convert it to a date. I can retrieve the string fine (and it logs out as expected).

Comment: Replace the `Z` in your format specifier with `z`. Read the documentation about the format specifiers to see why.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have already tried that as well... I actually started with the lowercase z as I started by reading the docs. I still get null.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your `dateString` has any whitespace on either end or a newline?

Comment: @rmaddy, just checked. No whitespace or newlines in the dateString. I appreciate your help. I am really stumped here. Especially because I can put in a static string date and it works fine.

Comment: @rmaddy I stand corrected. While there is not whitespace in the rss feed it seems that a space is being added to the end of the string. I added a space to the end of the dateformat and boom! Worked. Thanks so so much!